# Oracle SQL Query In Python with date User Input

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas

I'm trying to run SQL Query in python but I'm getting Error `not a valid month while passing dates using user input`.

The table has a date column in "`MM/DD/YYYY`" format. I'm passing date as "`YYYY-MM-DD`"

Here is the Query.

```
SELECT
  substr(PLACEMENT_DESC, 1, INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1) - 1) AS "'Placement#'",
  SUM(VIEWS) AS "'Delivered_Impresion'",
  SUM(CLICKS) AS "'Clicks'",
  SUM(CONVERSIONS) AS "'Conversion'"
FROM TFR_REP.DAILY_SALES_MV
WHERE (IO_ID = {})
AND (DAY_DESC BETWEEN to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
GROUP BY PLACEMENT_ID,
         PLACEMENT_DESC
ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID".format(self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)
```

**Here is the python Code:**
the code is too big, so I'm just putting a part of reading SQL.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
import config
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

class Summary():
    def __init__(self,config):
        self.config=config

    def connect_TFR_summary(self):

        #sql_VDX_summary="select * from (select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", SDATE as "'Start_Date'", EDATE as "'End_Date'", initcap(CREATIVE_DESC)  as "'Placement_Name'",COST_TYPE_DESC as "'Cost_type'",UNIT_COST as "'Unit_Cost'",BUDGET as "'Planned_Cost'",BOOKED_QTY as "'Booked_Imp#Booked_Eng'" from TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV where (IO_ID = {}) AND (DATA_SOURCE = 'KM') AND SDATE >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("'{}'", 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AND EDATE <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("'{}'",'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AND CREATIVE_DESC IN(SELECT DISTINCT CREATIVE_DESC FROM TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV) ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID) WHERE Placement_Name Not IN ('Pre-Roll - Desktop','Pre-Roll - Desktop + Mobile','Pre-Roll – Desktop + Mobile','Pre-Roll - In-Stream/Mobile Blend','Pre-Roll - Mobile','Pre-Roll -Desktop','Pre-Roll - In-Stream')".format(
           # self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)
        sql_VDX_summary="select * from (select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", SDATE as "'Start_Date'", EDATE as "'End_Date'", initcap(CREATIVE_DESC)  as "'Placement_Name'",COST_TYPE_DESC as "'Cost_type'",UNIT_COST as "'Unit_Cost'",BUDGET as "'Planned_Cost'",BOOKED_QTY as "'Booked_Imp#Booked_Eng'" from TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV where (IO_ID = {}) AND (DATA_SOURCE = 'KM') AND SDATE >= TO_DATE('{}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND EDATE <= TO_DATE('{}','YYYY-MM-DD') AND CREATIVE_DESC IN(SELECT DISTINCT CREATIVE_DESC FROM TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV) ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID) WHERE Placement_Name Not IN ('Pre-Roll - Desktop','Pre-Roll - Desktop + Mobile','Pre-Roll – Desktop + Mobile','Pre-Roll - In-Stream/Mobile Blend','Pre-Roll - Mobile','Pre-Roll -Desktop','Pre-Roll - In-Stream')".format(
            self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)
        sql_VDX_MV="select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", sum(IMPRESSIONS) as "'Impression'", sum(ENGAGEMENTS) as "'Eng'", sum(DPE_ENGAGEMENTS) as "'Deep'", sum(CPCV_COUNT) as "'Completions'" from TFR_REP.KEY_METRIC_MV WHERE (IO_ID = {}) AND (DAY_DESC BETWEEN to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) GROUP BY PLACEMENT_ID, PLACEMENT_DESC ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID".format(
            self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE,self.config.EDATE)
        sql_Display_summary="select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", SDATE as "'Start_Date'", EDATE as "'End_Date'", CREATIVE_DESC  as "'Placement_Name'", COST_TYPE_DESC as "'Cost_type'",UNIT_COST as "'Unit_Cost'",BUDGET as "'Planned_Cost'", BOOKED_QTY as "'Booked_Imp#Booked_Eng'" FROM TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV where (IO_ID = {}) AND SDATE >= TO_DATE('{}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND EDATE <= TO_DATE('{}','YYYY-MM-DD') AND DATA_SOURCE = 'SalesFile' ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID".format(
            self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)
        #sql_Display_MV="select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", sum(VIEWS) as "'Delivered_Impresion'", sum(CLICKS) as "'Clicks'", sum(CONVERSIONS) as "'Conversion'" from TFR_REP.DAILY_SALES_MV WHERE (IO_ID = {}) AND (DAY_DESC BETWEEN to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) GROUP BY PLACEMENT_ID, PLACEMENT_DESC ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID".format(
            #self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)

        sql_Display_MV = "select * from TFR_REP.DAILY_SALES_MV"

        sql_preroll_summary="select * from (select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", SDATE as "'Start_Date'", EDATE as "'End_Date'", initcap(CREATIVE_DESC)  as "'Placement_Name'",COST_TYPE_DESC as "'Cost_type'",UNIT_COST as "'Unit_Cost'",BUDGET as "'Planned_Cost'",BOOKED_QTY as "'Booked_Imp#Booked_Eng'" from TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV where (IO_ID = {}) AND SDATE >= TO_DATE('{}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND EDATE <= TO_DATE('{}','YYYY-MM-DD') AND (DATA_SOURCE = 'KM') AND CREATIVE_DESC IN(SELECT DISTINCT CREATIVE_DESC FROM TFR_REP.SUMMARY_MV) ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID) WHERE Placement_Name IN ('Pre-Roll - Desktop','Pre-Roll - Desktop + Mobile','Pre-Roll – Desktop + Mobile','Pre-Roll - In-Stream/Mobile Blend','Pre-Roll - Mobile','Pre-Roll -Desktop','Pre-Roll - In-Stream')".format(
            self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)
        sql_preroll_mv="select substr(PLACEMENT_DESC,1,INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1)-1) as "'Placement#'", sum(IMPRESSIONS) as "'Impression'", sum(CPCV_COUNT) as "'Completions'" from TFR_REP.KEY_METRIC_MV WHERE (IO_ID = {}) AND (DAY_DESC BETWEEN to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('{}'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) GROUP BY PLACEMENT_ID, PLACEMENT_DESC ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID".format(
            self.config.IO_ID, self.config.SDATE, self.config.EDATE)

        return sql_VDX_summary,sql_Display_summary,sql_preroll_summary,sql_Display_MV,sql_VDX_MV,sql_preroll_mv

    def read_query_summary(self):
        sql_VDX_summary,sql_Display_summary,sql_preroll_summary,sql_Display_MV,sql_VDX_MV,sql_preroll_mv=self.connect_TFR_summary()
        read_sql_Display_mv=pd.read_sql(sql_Display_MV,self.config.conn)
```

Comment: what's the datatype of `DAY_DESC` in the table?

Comment: can you post your python code?

Comment: @Fire See edited post.

Comment: im not so familiar with panda, but could you print self.config.SDATE and self.config.EDATE, to see if they match the format you specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are passing dates in `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format and `DAY_DESC` is date type, you could use date literals, which are ANSI standard and avoid `TO_DATE`

```
SELECT substr(PLACEMENT_DESC, 1, INSTR(PLACEMENT_DESC, '.', 1) - 1) AS "'Placement#'"
    ,SUM(VIEWS) AS "'Delivered_Impresion'"
    ,SUM(CLICKS) AS "'Clicks'"
    ,SUM(CONVERSIONS) AS "'Conversion'"
FROM TFR_REP.DAILY_SALES_MV
WHERE IO_ID = {}
    AND DAY_DESC BETWEEN DATE '{}'
        AND DATE '{}'
GROUP BY PLACEMENT_ID
    ,PLACEMENT_DESC
ORDER BY PLACEMENT_ID;
```

> The table has a date column in "MM/DD/YYYY" format

`Date` datatypes don't have any formats in database. It is just the display that varies according to you session parameters. However, If you mean  `DAY_DESC` is of string (`CHAR/VARCHAR2`)type, you could use it after converting it as:-

```
TO_DATE(DAY_DESC,'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN DATE '{}' AND DATE '{}'
```

Please avoid storing dates as character strings in databases.